# Default login data for Magento demo store backend?

Tags: admin, login

Whats the login data for the Magento demo store backend found here: http://demo-admin.magentocommerce.com/index.php/admin/

It used to be admin and admin123 if I remember it correctly, but that doesn't work anymore.

Ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no Magento Commerce ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schedule your own Magento demo here

https://magento.com/schedule-a-demo

Hope it may work!

Comment: Thats the enterprise edition, isnt it? I want the community edition demo store.

Comment: The link is no longer working